# get device with mount point

Tags: command-line, mount, python, filesystem

there's a way to get the device name `(/dev/sdx)` with the mounted folder? i mean, get the assosiated device in a mount point using the mounted folder as the reference, or make a python dictionary with the `mount points : devices`...

i know that `mount -l` can get me the mounted file system info, but i don't really know how to strip it to make the dictionary...

any help?

Regards...

Comment: See this [python udisks - enumerating device information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067005/python-udisks-enumerating-device-information) at Stackoverflow and this could help too: [How to find the mountpoint a file resides on?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453602/how-to-find-the-mountpoint-a-file-resides-on).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is totally unrelated to Ubuntu, but here you are:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess

mounts = {}

for line in subprocess.check_output(['mount', '-l']).split('\n'):
    parts = line.split(' ')
    if len(parts) > 2:
        mounts[parts[2]] = parts[0]

print mounts
```

Comment: thank, this did the job, but it's having problems when a tag has a space on it, it only displays the first word...

Comment: The code is just an illustration, I didn't try to write a robust production ready program. You can try using `cat /proc/mounts` command instead of `mount` - maybe it's output is easier to parse.

Comment: thanks again, i managed to get it working using `cat /proc/mounts` and replacing some things with `string.replace()`

Comment: Why not create a Java app for doing what can be achieved with a 27 character command line? Sorry, couldn't resist.

Comment: @January: Firstly, it's Python :) Secondly, the OP stated she/he needs a Python dictionary, supposedly to be used in an application. Piping the output through `cut` does not solve the problem of converting the output into something meaningful for a program.

Comment: @Sergey: well, yes, you have a point here. That's why I upped your answer. Nonetheless, I shudder when I see the code above.

Answer (score 3):

```
mount | cut -f 1,3 -d ' '
```

Explanation: `cut` is a handy little tool for splitting lines using a delimiter character (specified by the `-d` option) and selecting some of the fields for output (using a comma separated argument list to the `-f` option). Since the `mount` output is regular and delimited by spaces, the above outputs the first and third column, omitting "on" and the remainder of the line.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the Gio interface? I like these solutions better than executing a bash command and parsing its output. This way you can catch exceptions and have more control.

Here's a little example:

```
>>> from gi.repository import Gio
>>> vm = Gio.VolumeMonitor.get()
>>> for v in vm.get_volumes():
...     print v.get_name()
```

See the documentation for much more interesting methods.

[GVolumeMonitor](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GVolumeMonitor.html)

[GVolume](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GVolume.html)

[Gmount](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GMount.html)

Comment: mm... this looks better, i'll try it when i get home :)